# MYSQL having multiple Selects that corresond with different where conditions

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to execute one mysql statement where I have a select that is not part of the where condition. 
this is my code:

```
    SELECT oil.empid
     , oil.mileage
     , oil.`date`
     , max(oil.mileage) AS expr1

FROM
  oil
WHERE
  oil.mileage < (SELECT max(oil.mileage) AS expr1
                 FROM
                   oil)

GROUP BY
  oil.empid
ORDER BY
  oil.mileage
```

now this selects the second largest mileage but what i want is both the second and largest mileage. I believe that i just need to select max(mileage) outside of the WHERE but im not sure how to do that. Thanks for any help

edit:
If the data entered for these 1497 was

mileage: 100 , 100000 , and 200000

and for empid 2000

mileage: 100 , 1500 , 5000

I would want this:

```
 empid|2nd max  | max
 1497 | 100000  |  200000
 2000 | 1500    |  5000
```

Comment: How about omitting the where clause altogether and limiting your query to 2 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` in MySQL's `ORDER BY` clause to find the second mileage. This way you gain by not using the expensive `GROUP BY`.

(Update) after the clarifications by the OP:

```
SELECT oil.empid
     , oil.mileage
     , oil.date
FROM
        oil
    JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT empid
          FROM oil
        ) AS emp
            ON  oil.empid = emp.empid
            AND oil.mileage >= 
                ( SELECT mileage
                  FROM oil AS o
                  WHERE o.empid = emp.empid
                  ORDER BY mileage DESC
                  LIMIT 1  OFFSET 1
                )
ORDER BY
    oil.empid
  , oil.mileage               --- ASC or DESC here, your choice
;
```

Comment: again this does the same as brians code and only returns 2 rows of 1 empid (in this case empid =employee id) and i have more than one empid sorry if this was not clear

Comment: Show us some sample data and you want as result then.

Comment: Do you want the 2 largest mileages for **every** empid? That's a different query ...

Comment: This is what i want! i have been trying to get this to no avail. Thank you so much kind sir. just a simple question, is it possible to grab the max mileage first then the second max? I apoligize for my lack of knowledge on the matter, im just learning sql now and its slowly making sense to me.

Comment: No worries, this is a complex (but not uncommon) question. Retagging your question. There's even a tag for this!: [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a naive response, but why not just do this:

```
SELECT oil.empid
      , oil.mileage
      , oil.`date`
      , max(oil.mileage) as expr1
FROM oil
GROUP BY oil.empid, oil.`date`
ORDER BY oil.mileage DESC
LIMIT 2
```

**UPDATE**
Given OP's update it's clear that we need an entirely different sort of query, something like this:

```
SELECT outer.empid
       , (SELECT first.mileage
          FROM oil as first
          WHERE first.empid = outer.empid
          ORDER BY first.mileage DESC
          LIMIT 1) AS max
       , (SELECT second.mileage
          FROM oil as second
          WHERE second.empid = outer.empid
          ORDER BY second.mileage DESC
          LIMIT 1
          OFFSET 1) as 2nd_max
FROM oil as outer
```

Comment: this would work if i only wanted 2 rows returned total i have multiple empid's and it only returns one this way.

Comment: @BluGeni Can you update your question with a sample of the **results** that you're trying to get with your query?

Comment: Hmm... okay, so to get what you are looking for you'll need to use correlated subqueries... I'll update momentarily.